# RDS connection time out in rush hours (with ~50.000 HTTP requests)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We're using RDS on a db.t2.large instance. And an auto-scaling group of EC2's is writing data to the database during the day. In rush hours we're having about 50.000 HTTP requests each which read/write MySQL data.

This varies each day, but for today's example, during an hour:

We're seeing "Connect Error (2002) Connection timed out" from our PHP instances, about 187 times a minute.

- RDS CPU won't raise above 50%
- DB Connections won't go above 30 (max is set to 5000).
- Free storage is ~ 300G (Disk size is large to provide high IOPS )
- Write IOPS hit 1500 burst but drop to 900 because burst limit has expired, after rush hours.
- Read IOPS are hitting 300 each 10mins and around 150 in between.
- Disk Write Throughput averages between 20 and 25 MB/Sec
- Disk Read Throughput between 0,75 and 1,5 MB/Sec
- CPU Credit Balance is around 500, so we don't have a need for the CPU burst.

And when it comes to the network, I see a potential limit we're hitting:

- Network Receive Throughput reaches 1.41 MB/Second and stays around 1.5 MB/Seconds during an hour.
- During this time Network Transmit 5 a 5.2 MB/Second with drops to 4 MB/Second each 10 min which concurs with our cronjobs which are processing data (mainly reading)

I've tried placing the EC2's in different or the same AZ's, but this has no effect

During this time I can connect fine from my local workstation via SSH Tunnel (EC2 -> RDS). And from the EC2 to the RDS as well.

The PHP scripts are set to time-out after 5 sec of trying to connect to ensure a fast response. I've increased this limit to 15 sec now for some scripts.

But which limit are we hitting on RDS? Before we start migrating or changing instances types we'd like to known the source of this problem. I've also just enabled Enhanced Monitoring to get more details on this issue.

If more info needed, I'll gladly elaborate where needed.

Thanks!

**Update 25/01/2016**

On recommendation of datasage we increased the RDS disk size to 500 GB which gives us 1500 IOPS with 3600 burst, it uses around 1200 IOPS (so not even bursting now) and the time outs still occur.

Connection time-outs are set to 5 sec and 15 sec as mentioned before, shows no difference.

**Update 26/01/2016**

RDS Screenshot from our peak hours:

[image: RDS Monitoring]

**Update 28/01/2016**

I've changed the setting `sync_bin_log` to 0, because initially I thought we were hitting the EBS throughput limits (GP-SSD 160 Mbit/s), this gives us a significant drop in disk throughput and the IOPS are lower as well, but we still see the connection time outs occur.

When we plot the times that the errors occur we're seeing that each minute around :40 seconds the time-outs start happening during about 25seconds, then no errors for about 35 secs again and it starts again. This during the peak hour of our incoming traffic.

Comment: T2 instances use a credit model. What does the credit balance look like when are experiencing the timeouts?

Comment: I've improved the formatting on the question since I already noted CPU credit balance :-)  CPU Credits are around 500 and not decreasing much.

Comment: In that case it would appear that you are hitting the IOPS limits. General Purpose SSD has 3 IOPs per GB. That includes read and write. If you can't reduce your IOPs, you may need to look at switched to provisioned IOPS

Comment: what's the size of the EC2 instances?

Comment: The EC2's are t2.medium and we have 3-5 running during these peak hours. I've increased the size to 500 GB which gives us 1500 IOPS and 3600 burst, but CloudWatch shows no higher than 1200 used, so it's not even bursting now and it still happens.

Comment: as an experiment why not increase the RDS instance size from a t2.large to a m4.xlarge?  This will give you a "Network Performance" of "High" as opposed to "Low to Moderate" on a t2.large.  As well as other performance advantages.  But if the graphs you include in the question are correct then they seem to be saying that the database does not have a problem, the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Thanks @Vorsprung, we were planning on upgrading the instance indeed during low traffic hours. Which was last weekend, now we are running two days without errors. So this was indeed the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was the Network Performance keeping us back. When we upgraded our RDS instance to an m4.xlarge (with High Network Performance) the issues were resolved.

This was a last resort for us, but it solved our problem in the end.